# Reorder a matrix according to the mean of its rows

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Given a matrix `A m x n` I would like to reorganize its rows so that going from row `1` to row `n` there is a growing mean value over the row.

Is there a simple way of doing so?

E.g. Input `A = [5 5 5; 3 3 3; 2 2 2; 4 4 4]` Output `B = [2 2 2; 3 3 3; 4 4 4; 5 5 5]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean *rows*, not *columns*; and *mean*, not *median*:

```
[~, ind] = sort(mean(A.')); %'// get indices of sorting the row means
B = A(ind,:); %// apply that sorting to the matrix
```

(you may save some time using `sum` instead of `mean`).

If you really mean *columns*:

```
[~, ind] = sort(mean(A));
B = A(:,ind);
```

If you really mean *median*, replace `mean` by `median`.

---